# $(...).anchorAnimate is not a function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function

I have two problems on my website.

There is a menu, and if you click on a link then the browser scrolls to the point (id) of the link. A few days ago everything worked fine, but not now. I didn't work on the webpage, so I don't know where the problem is.

Here is my Code:

```
jQuery.fn.anchorAnimate = function(settings) {     

    settings = jQuery.extend({
            speed : 1000     
        }, settings);        

        return this.each(function(){        
            var caller = this         
                $(caller).click(function (event) {               
                event.preventDefault()            
                var locationHref = window.location.href             
                var elementClick = $(caller).attr("href")             
                var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top - 135;             
            $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination}, settings.speed, function() {                 
                //window.location.hash = elementClick            
                    });             
                return false;        
            })     
                }) 
                };



$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("li.anchorLink a").anchorAnimate(); 
    });
```

Can you help me?

Comment: You forgot a semi-colon `;` in `var caller = this`

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you load JQuery library first and then your jquery plugin. Basically it doesn't recognize your current file, because Jquery wasn't loaded / wasn't found.